# Find unique rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given some unit vector $v \in R^3$, consider the set of linear transformations $S$ such that if $L \in S$,

- $L(e_3) = v$
- The matrix of $L$ has determinant 1
- There is no rotation about $e_3$

I believe $S$ contains only a single element. Given $v$, how would you find this element?

I have tried considering the angles $\phi$ and $\theta$ that $v$ makes with the $xz$ and $yz$ planes respectively, and from there constructing a rotation matrix sending

- $L(e_1) = (cos(\phi), 0, sin(\phi))$
- $L(e_2) = (0, cos(\theta), sin(\theta))$
- $L(e_3) = v$

But I don't seem to be getting the results I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For there to be no rotation about $e_3$, the axis of rotation must lie in the $xy$-plane. A good candidate for this axis is $e_3\times v$, which will also give you the sine of the rotation angle. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Ah that's a great idea! Yes, lets hope I'm capable of taking it from there :). Thank you my friend.

Comment: Do you know where the flaw in my original logic is, btw?

Comment: @jammie It’s hard to say. Looking at those angles might’ve led somewhere, but I can’t see how you decided that the angles that $v$ makes with its projections onto the $xz$ and $yz$ planes are the right amounts by which to rotate the $x$- and $y$-axes about each other. It’s immediately apparent that the construction is incorrect because the only way to have $L(e_1)\cdot L(e_2)=0$, which you must have for a rigid motion, is for $\sin\phi=0$ or $\sin\theta=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that “there is no rotation about $e_3$” means that the rotation must be a composition of rotations about the $x$- and $y$-axes, rotating first about the $x$-axis gives $$R_v=\pmatrix{\cos\theta&0&\sin\theta\\0&1&0\\-\sin\theta&0&\cos\theta}\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&\cos\phi&-\sin\phi\\0&\sin\phi&\cos\phi} = \pmatrix{\cos\theta&\sin\phi\sin\theta&\cos\phi\sin\theta \\ 0&\cos\phi&-\sin\phi \\ -\sin\theta&\sin\phi\cos\theta&\cos\phi\cos\theta}.$$ Setting the last column to $v$ and doing a bit of algebra gives $$R_v=\pmatrix{
{v_z\over\sqrt{v_x^2+v_z^2}} & -{v_xv_y\over\sqrt{v_x^2+v_z^2}} & v_x \\
0 & \sqrt{v_x^2+v_z^2} & v_y \\
-{v_x\over\sqrt{v_x^2+v_z^2}} & -{v_yv_z\over\sqrt{v_x^2+v_z^2}} & v_z
}.$$ The first column is a unit vector in the $xz$-plane orthogonal to the projection of $v$ onto this plane, so you were on the right track in looking at the relationship of $v$ to this plane. You can verify by inspection that this vector is also orthogonal to $v$. The middle column is the cross product of the other two, which is what is needed to end up with an orthogonal matrix. Note that the denominator vanishes if $v$ is a multiple of $e_2$, but if that’s the case then we need only a rotation about the $x$-axis.

If you instead rotate about the $y$-axis first, you get a different rotation matrix with a similar structure. The last column is, of course, $v$, the second column lies in the $yz$-plane and is orthogonal to $v$’s projection, and the first is the cross product of the other two.

With this interpretation, the resulting rotation axis will not in general lie in the $xy$-plane.